# Toolbar DisplayHomeAsUp Btn id

Tags: android

I have a trivial problem with the HomeAsUp Button in My activity, its not being Executing or more concise the Id I'm checking its not the correct one, So I have to Ask, What its The id for the HomeAsUp button on the Toolbar ?

My code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    log.d("item i "+item.getItemId());
    log.d("Home id "+android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home);
    log.d("Home id from R "+R.id.home);
    log.d("Home id from R "+R.id.homeAsUp);
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.a_profile_menu_item_edit) {
        showProfileEdit();
        return true;
    } else if (item.getItemId() == android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home) {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And from those logs im printing this is what they printed:

```
D/Profile[onOptionsItemSelected] - 121﹕ item id 16908332
D/Profile[onOptionsItemSelected] - 122﹕ Home id 2131492868
D/Profile[onOptionsItemSelected] - 123﹕ Home id from R 2131492868
D/Profile[onOptionsItemSelected] - 124﹕ Home id from R 2131492877
```

So my item.id is 16908332 but neither R.id.home, R.id.homeAsUp, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home are the correct ones, any help is appreciated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Up button not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940056/android-up-button-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need the **android**.R.id.home with the id 16908332.
pay attention to the **android** in the prefix.