# Android Up button not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, r.java-file

I am trying to manually implement the actions that must take place when the up button on the actionbar is pressed but for some reason nothing happens when I press it.

here is my code:

```
public class ActivityOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_one);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivityTwo();
            }
        });
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivityThree();
            }
        });
    }


    void openActivityTwo(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    void openActivityThree(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityThree.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_one, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        else if(id == R.id.homeAsUp){
            Log.i("","Up is pressed");
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I understand that I have to explicitly assign a parent activity for the activity **I want to implement up navigation on the manifest file**, but problem is that this activity has multiple parents so I thought calling the `finish()` method when the up button is pressed on this activity will be the better approach.

I have already tried both `id == R.id.home` and `id ==  R.id.homeAsUp` and they both do not work. I do not know if it is because I am using `AppCompactActivity` or what Please help

Comment: you are starting another activity in button click, not in actionButtonBack click

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is how you can implement this, try this code

**use android.R.id.home instead of R.id.home or R.id.homeAsUp**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //use onBackPressed() OR finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will buy you cupcakes one day, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do it is to override `public boolean onNavigateUp()` just like overriding `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: ive literaly implemented onNavigateUp(), onItemSelected(), and added .setNavigationOnCLickListener() . nothing will allow me to go to the previous activity.?

Comment: @filthy_wizard have you tried to call onBackPressed()

Answer (score 0):

Using android studio 3.6.2 I've found that the Up button is not displayed by default in my apps, but it can be easily added..

Go to AndroidManifest.xml and update each activity that needs an Up button as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".yourClassName"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
    android:value="com.example.yourPackageName" />
</activity>
```

The target destination for the Up button is set by changing parentActivityName. In this example I have set it as '.MainActivity' but you can change that to whatever activity you want the user to navigate to.